# Как перевести (String incrypt) в base64 и обратно?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String incrypt = "qwerty12345";

    }


    public void crypt_text(View v) {


    }

    public void incrypt_text(View v) {


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Кодирование:

```
String originalInput = "test input";
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(originalInput.getBytes());
```

Декодирование:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
```

Это все в самом простом виде. [Здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode) можно посмотреть больше

Answer (score 0):

Использовать [android.util.Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64).

Comment: А можно запустить Base64. на API <26 РУГАЕТСЯ

Comment: По ссылке написано "Added in API level 8", так что запустить можно на любом не меньшем 8-го.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/496805)

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka на самом деле ответ и без ссылки даже полноценен. Задача элементарна и расширить ответ можно только написав код за автора вопроса.